# After migrating to Spring Boot 2.1.7 RELEASE-initializeBean not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

After  migrating spring4.1.7 to spring boot2.1.7 Release.Its showing an error for bean creation while initializing application context.

Error Log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'localConfig' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:771)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    ... 25 more
```

ServiceConfiguration Class

```
@Configuration
@Profile(ContextProfileNames.SERVICE)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.get.services")
@Import(ControllerConfiguration.class)
public class ServiceConfiguration implements InitializingBean
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean(name = "localConfig")
    @DependsOn(BeanNames.CONFIGURATION_FACTORY)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public LocalDataSourceConfiguration getLocalDataSourceConfiguration() throws XEDecryptionException
    {
        ConfigurationFactory configurationFactory = (ConfigurationFactory) context
                .getBean(BeanNames.CONFIGURATION_FACTORY);
        LocalDataSourceConfig localDataSourceConfig = configurationFactory.getLocalDataSourceConfiguration();

        LocalDataSourceConfiguration localDataSourceConfiguration = new LocalDataSourceConfiguration(
                localDataSourceConfig.isMsSqlConfigured(), localDataSourceConfig.isSybaseConfigured(),
                localDataSourceConfig.getServiceConfigurationMode(), getLocalDBConfigurationInfo(
                        localDataSourceConfig.getDbConfigurations().getDbConfigInfo(), configurationFactory));
        localDataSourceConfiguration
                .setUseRisExamIdAsAccession(Boolean.parseBoolean(localDataSourceConfig.getUseRisExamIdAsAccession()));
        localDataSourceConfiguration.setCpacsNameFormat(localDataSourceConfig.getCpacsNameFormat());
        localDataSourceConfiguration.setTableCacheRefreshInterval(localDataSourceConfig.getTableCacheRefreshInterval());
        localDataSourceConfiguration.setAuthorityMatchingMode(localDataSourceConfig.getAuthorityMatchingMode());
        return localDataSourceConfiguration;
    }
 }
```

How can i resolve this issue?.did i miss anything?

Comment: Your configuration is depending on a profile and a bean being available, make sure that you enabled the profile and that the other bean is available. Also I would strongly suggest to not the the `@DependsOn` but rather inject the dependency into the `getLocalDataSourceConfiguration` directly. That will save you a lookup (and injcting the `ApplicationContext`) and the `@DependsOn` as Spring can now figure that out by itself. Finally be aware that by upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1 you are upgrading (and skipping) 4 versions of Spring! which might need some attention as well!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added @profile in main class.Issue resolved